# How to create a off/on slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

So I have seen things like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DcJN.png)

It basically is a off/on slider. I thought that you could use a range for this and have the max set to 2 and minimum set to 1, but that has low support. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a wealth of examples out there like this - https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/material-design-switch

The solution is to style a checkbox to display as the "switch" and use Pseudo selectors to dispaly  on/off based on the checked property of that hidden checkbox.

Note - this is NOT my solution, but one that I have found useful in other projects. Bootsnipp is a valuable resource that may offer dev's a wealth of examples and snippets. (I am not affilitated with that site)

```js
function toggle(state) {
  var el = document.getElementById('someSwitchOptionDefault');
  el.checked =state
  }
```

```css
.material-switch span:hover {
cursor:pointer}

.material-switch span:first-of-type {
    position:relative; 
    top 100px; 
    left:0
   }
   
 .material-switch span:last-of-type {
    position:relative; 
    top 30px; 
    left:100px
   }
   
   
  .material-switch > input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;   
}

.material-switch > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative; 
    top:10px;
    left:30px;
    width: 40px;  
}

.material-switch > label::before {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 8px;
    content: '';
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    width: 40px;
}
.material-switch > label::after {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    content: '';
    height: 24px;
    left: -4px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 24px;
}
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background: #e60000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    background: #e60000;
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="material-switch">
  <span onclick="toggle(false)">Off</span>
  <input id="someSwitchOptionDefault" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="someSwitchOptionDefault" class="label-default"></label>
   <span onclick="toggle(true)">On</span>
</div>
```